# Loop through variable

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I need to loop through variable and write returned values into DB.
Here is my code so far:

```
<cffunction name="csv">
    <cffile action="read" file="test.csv" variable="csvfile" charset="utf-8">
    <cfset csv_query = app.csvToQuery.CSVToQuery(CSV = csvFile.Trim()) />

    <cfloop query="csv_query">
        <cfset getInfo = app.directory.searchAll(
            findNo = "#replace(csv_query.column_1, "test", "", 'all')#",
            findBy = "Null"
        )>

        <!--- <cfdump var="#getInfo#"> --->
        <cfoutput><cfdump var="#getInfo.NAME#"></cfoutput>

        <cftry>
            <cfquery datasource="#app.dsn#">
                INSERT INTO WRITEINFO (
                    Name,
                ) VALUES (
                    '#val(getInfo.NAME)#',
                )
            </cfquery>
                <cfcatch type="database">
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>

    </cfloop>
</cffunction>
```

It writes into DB, but it only writes the first value it gets. I am already looping through query, and when I dumped the values(`<cfdump var="#getInfo.NAME#">`), I can see all the values I needed, but they're just not inserted into DB

Comment: Any errors? Could you add dump to the catch block?

Comment: I think you are having more that one values in <cfdump var="#getInfo.NAME#">, but it writes only first value into DB. right ? If YES you need to loop the `getInfo` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if this fails silently. You catch database errors but don't do anything in case of an error. One insert statement works. On other inserts it might fail (e.g. unique index violation, "Name" inserted to long for the column in the table, etc.). Maybe get rid of the try/catch block (at least temporarily) and see what happens.